# What type of construct is a for loop in JavaScript (or Python or R)

Tags: javascript, r, python-3.x, theory

I understand how to write a for loop and what it does. If I wanted, however,  to understand it more deeply, could I describe it as a  block statement that with a expected group of keywords and appropriate syntax is used for (a type of) conditional execution?

Comment: Are you just trying to paraphrase what a for loop is?

Comment: @luk2302 I want to be able to describe conditional statements (in general) more fully. I'm using a for loop as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say yes. A for loop is a control-flow block structure, almost always with a calculable finite—often pre-defined—number of iterations, that performs the code inside the block. It often includes iterators so that the same algorithm within the block is applied to different elements as one traverses data.

Comment: *"a pre-defined number of iterations"* - no.

Comment: Sure. That may be based of the length of an item, or calculated from some other data source, but for loops need an iterator of some kind that has a known finite magnitude. Otherwise it is a do/while type loop.

Comment: `for (;;) {}` is a valid `for` loop. `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {i += 2;}` as well but the number of iterations is not predefined.

Comment: @luk2302 I forgot C's ridiculosity of the empty triple. That should be taken out and shot, but you are technically correct. I'll edit. As for the latter, we know that there will be 5 iterations. So even though it's not explicit, it is well-defined prior to the call due to the parameters.

Comment: Even in python you can do `for a in data: data.append(a)` which will run indefinitely. I fully agree with the "often" / "almost always" statement ;)